# How to get input intensity of gamepad using old input manager?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I’m looking for a way to get the input intensity of a controller joystick when using a Xbox/PS5 Controller in Unity using the old Input Manager. Anything would help, I can’t find any resources on this subject, thanks!

Currently, the only results I’m getting are -1,0,1 using the old input manager

Answer (score 0):

I think you already have your desired output. The method `Input.GetAxis()` returns a value between -1 and 1, representing the intensity of the joystick input. A value of -1 indicates that the joystick is fully pressed to the left, a value of 0 indicates that the joystick is not being pressed, and a value of 1 indicates that the joystick is fully pressed to the right.

To get the input intensity of a specific joystick, such as the left joystick on an Xbox controller, you can use the following code:

```
float leftJoystickIntensity = Input.GetAxis("LeftJoystickX");
```